# Are there any twin-engine turboprop airplanes with FADEC and 6 seats?

Tags: turboprop, multi-engine, fadec

Are there any twin-engine airplanes with FADEC with 6 seats? Is there nothing equivalent to DA62 in the turboprop world with slightly bigger interior and club seats?

Answer (score 2):

There are currently no General Aviation twin turboprop aircraft with FADEC. Turboprops have always had separate power levers and propeller condition levers.

I believe the first GA turboprops with FADEC are the single engine [Pilatus PC-12 NGX](https://www.pilatus-aircraft.com/en/fly/pc-12)  and [TBM 960.](https://www.tbm.aero/page/tbm960)

[image]

[image]